# Does Google Life Sciences API support dependencies and parallel commands?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

From what I can tell from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/), the Google Cloud Life Sciences API (v2beta) allows you to define a "pipeline" with multiple commands in it, but these run sequentially.

Am I correct in thinking there is no way to have some commands run in parallel, and for a group of commands to be dependent on others (that is, to not start running until their predecessors have finished)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot run commands in parallel, or in such a way that the process is dependent upon the completion of some other process.

When you run commands using the commands[] flag. This is exactly the same as passing the CMD parameter to a Docker container(as this is exactly what you are doing). The commands[] flag overrides the CMD arguments passed to the Docker container at runtime. If the container in using an Entrypoint then the commands[] flag will override the Entrypoint argument values for the container

You can review the official here;

[Method: projects.locations.pipelines.run](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/reference/rest/v2beta/projects.locations.pipelines/run)

[gcloud command-line tool examples](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/reference/gcloud-examples)

[gcloud beta lifesciences](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/lifesciences/)